Why my usb drive suddenly became read-only?
A month ago, my usb drive could delete, store and move files but all of a sudden it became read-only. It's a SanDisk cruzer blade 32 gbs without a physical lock switch and the storage is not full.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
